# Startup.cs error (ASP.Net Core configuration)

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to set up an ASP.Net Core application to read in configuration settings from a json file.  I am using VS2015 and .NetCore 1.0 (with .Net Core Tools preview 2). I am having problems getting a simple piece of boiler plate code to compile.

I am using the following code, which was published at
http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/03/21/configure-aspnetcore.html

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights 
            // pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

However, the IDE/compiler complains that 'the name "Configuration" does not exist in the current context' (last line of code).  The only suggestion from the IDE is to include Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. However this is a namespace which does not contain an object or property named "Configuration".

In addition 'AddApplicationInsightsSettings' fails with  does IConfigurationBuilder not contain a definition for AddApplicationInsightsSettings and no extension method AddApplicationInsightsSettings accepting a first argument of type IConfigurationBuilder  could be found

Any suggestions please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply add `Configuration` property to your `Startup` class, tutorial has missed this 'step':

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
```

`ConfigurationBuilder.Build()` method just returns instance of [IConfigurationRoot](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/Extensions/Configuration/IConfigurationRoot/), that you should save, if need to get settings further in Startup class (in `ConfigureServices` method for example).

Regarding second error, looks like you didn't add the [Application Insights](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started) dependency:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that answer.  Any clues about the second error ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I missed that.

Comment: In that post I assumed the readers use a new ASP.NET Core project from VS, where the property already exists. I will update that blog post. Thanks for the hint. :)